# Error trying to install DanfoJs, The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I am trying to install DanfoJS on **windows 10** using below command:

```
npm install danfojs-node
```

but I get following error when I run `npm start`

> Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path:

I tried to ran `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source` but still having problem.

and here is the package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "electron": "^10.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^2.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "danfojs-node": "^0.1.4",
    "electron-log": "^3.0.6",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "local-devices": "^2.0.0",
    "node-thermal-printer": "^4.1.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "ws": "^7.2.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.22",
    "xpath": "0.0.27",
    "yargs": "^14.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: Did you install tfjs-node ?

Comment: yes I did and still get the same issue

Comment: Could you create a new repository and try to install first tensorflow-node and then danfojs ?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: Could you please add the `package.json` to your question ?

Comment: sure I just did

Answer (score 0):

I was using a different node.js version that Electron was. so I installed node.js version is the same as the version of Electron is using (12.16.3) and that ***solved the problem***